# App doesn't support Samsung Galaxy Tab 7 inch displays

Tags: android, compatibility, android-screen-support

My app turns out to be not compatible with Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 with 7 inches display. However, I have included these lines in my manifest. What I need to change?

```
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="420" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="560" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="640" />
    <!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="420" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="480" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="560" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="640" />
</compatible-screens>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below code in your Manifest file :

```
<supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Comment: I want to exclude small and xlarge screens. That's why I have modified Manifest file. Considering this, what needs to be changed in your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Are there any features your app is using that the device does not have?

We ran into this a year ago with AUTOFOCUS for the rear camera, which a lot of 7-8" tablets don't seem to have.

EDIT: Based on Marat Kumar M's answer above, what you want to add, to exclude those two screen types, is the following:

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="false" />
```

Comment: No. App uses very basic functions and don't even need any special permissions.

Comment: Okay, huge coincidence, but I built an app last night that measures your screen density and size for you. It's on GitHub so go https://github.com/shobhik/ScreenCheck/blob/master/app/app-release.apk and hit download and run that on your device. That should tell you conclusively what size and density your tablet is.